# error when I use raisedButton in a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing my first flutter app and i created two classes. 
Those two classes represent two pages that i wish to navigate between and I am facing an issue with the "raisedButton". 
The first class has 2 widgets and the button only works in one of them! whenever I try to cut+ paste the button to the desired widget => I get the following error:

The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType()

I don't know what they mean by that. 
Any help is appreciated.

```dart
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _contactList(String name, String image,[BuildContext context]) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(image),
          radius: 35.0,
          child: Text(nameInitial,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0)),
        ),
        title: Text(name),
        trailing: RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Details'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Details()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please post all your code and let us examine

Comment: On top of posting your code, please, include your "flutter doctor -v"

Comment: I added the code that causes the error. I am trying to show a Tile that shows an avatar of the person , their name and then a button to go to another pager where more info of them can be found

Comment: The problem is likely coming from you passing null to `Navigator.push`. Where are you calling `_contactList(...)`?

Comment: can you add full minimal code which simulates your real issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a named route by calling the Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/home');  Named routes allow for parameter passing '/customer/:${customer.id}'. the routing paths are defined onGenerateRoute attribute assigned to routing information

```
class _AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget>{
bool _bright=false;
_brightnessCallback(). 
{setState(()=>_bright=!_bright);debugPrint("brightnessCallback fired");}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return MaterialApp(
title: "Flutter demo",
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
),
home: MyHome2Widget(),
onGenerateRoute: handleRoute

);
}}

Route<dynamic> handleRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings)
{
List<String> nameParam= routeSettings.name.split(":");
String name=nameParam[0];
//int id=int.tryParse(nameParam[1]);
Widget childWidget;
if(name=="/Home")
{
  childWidget=MyHome2Widget();
}else if(name=="/Summary")
{
  childWidget=SummaryWidget();
}
return MaterialPageRoute(
   builder:(context)=>childWidget
);
}
```